# Retrieve swf information with javascript

Tags: javascript, flash

I need to get some information of a swf "e-learning" movie. I need to know in wich part of it the user has stoped watching and or if user has watched until it's end. I am not developing a LMS, so I need just simple features. Are there any way to retrieve this information from within flash with javascript? If so, do you know where can I find some documentation about it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Adobe Flash's [**`ExternalInterface`**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) API to communicate between Javascript and ActionScript. ***Browser Support:*** IE 5.0+, Firefox 1.0+, Safari 1.3+, Opera, Chrome (versions N/A but old enough).

#### Flash TO Javascript Communication;

In your **AS3/Flash**:

```
function sendToJS(obj:Object):void {
    if (ExternalInterface.available) {
        ExternalInterface.call("onFlashCall", obj);
    }
}
```

In your **HTML/Javascript**:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onFlashCall(obj) {
            console.log("Data received from Flash: ", obj);
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

#### Javascript TO Flash Communication;

In your **AS3/Flash**:

```
public function onJavascriptCall(obj:Object):String 
{ 
    console.log("Data received from Javascript: ", obj);
} 
ExternalInterface.addCallback("sendToFlash", onJavascriptCall);
```

In your **HTML/Javascript**:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function sendToFlash(obj) {
            var flashElem = document.getElementById("flashObject");
            flashElem.sendToFlash(obj);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Embeded Flash SWF -->
<object id="flashObject"...> 
    ... 
    <embed name="flashObject".../> 
</object>
</body>
```

**Important:** In Flash, not to get a security error:
In the object tag for the SWF file in the containing HTML page, set the following parameter:

```
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
```

In the SWF file, add the following ActionScript:

```
flash.system.Security.allowDomain(sourceDomain);
```

### So, in your case:

Call `sendToJS()` method inside your player's corresponding event handlers:

```
protected function onStopClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    sendToJS("User has clicked the STOP button.");
}

protected function onPlaybackFinish(event:Event):void
{
    sendToJS("Playback is complete.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Onur YILDIRIM, I'll try this approach.